# Transfer DB files through Java sockets

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, sockets, file-transfer

Can we transfer Database files (.sql, .sqlite or any DB file) through java sockets. I tried transferring a sqlite file through buffer and int but both didn't work. Does any one have any idea?

Client and server side OS: Windows

Comment: If you're attempting to use cross-network storage, it might be better to overall ditch SQLite and go with a DB that would support this in the first place (MySQL, Postgre, etc). Then you could simply signal another program to do its updates from there.

Comment: @Rogue Thanks for your help. I need to transfer db files from one windows machine to another. Sorry for not mentioning the OS. I tried searching the net and its amazing how no one has attempted this.

Comment: Well, as outlined above, I still don't see much justifiable reason to. A centralized database would provide a much simpler use. If you wanted, you can even use a centralized controller that would handle writes and direct connecting users would only have read access.

Comment: @Rogue Sorry but I am new to all these can u explain your comment?

Comment: A controller would be able to receive a request for db access, and return network details to connect to a db for read access. MySQL has permissions, and you can make a user that had read-only permissions for it.